# Change first product image that is displayed on product page - Magento 2.3.5

Tags: product, magento2.3, product-images, magento2.3.5, gallery-image

How can we change the product image that is displayed first when the productpage is loaded?

At the moment this is the first image in line, but we want to change this to be the "base" image.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: You want to do this programatically?

Comment: @Joao71 Thanks for the reply. Yes that the main image that is first selected, is always the base image.